# Why is the bracha on mashed potatoes "haadama" despite being mashed up but the bracha on applesauce is "shahakol" unless there are pieces in it?

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, derabanan

Why is the bracha on mashed potatoes "haadama" despite being mashed up but the bracha on applesauce is "shahakol" unless there are pieces in it that are not mashed up?

Comment: I think it's because applesauce is pureed, not just mashed. An equivalent might be potato soup.

Answer (score 6):

In Rabbi Pinchos Bodner’s book “Halachos of Brachos” on page 406 and 409 he explains in the name of R’ Scheinberg, R’ Elyashiv, R’ Shlomo Zalman and others, that mashed potatoes should be hadama since one can readily recognize that it’s potatoes, whereas apple sauce you can’t tell that it comes from apples right away.